# I just lost 15 in one go – a fine?

Tags: support, reputation

This morning I was deducted 15 points in one go. Now 15 is not a multiple of 2, and in any case the rep level at the question itself seems unaffected. So is this some kind of swingeing great FINE, in which case I would like to hear the charges against me and file an appeal, or a BUG?

Answer (score 8):

It is probably due to your answer on "Should I use 'which' or 'that'?" having been accepted by the asker, and then un-accepted. An Accepted answer gives 15 points.

Comment: Much obliged to you!

Comment: @DavidPugh In fact, if you look on your reputation tab in your profile, you will see an Accept for the question and an Unaccept.

Comment: @Andrew: Sorry to be dense, but in my Profile I don't see anything calling itself a "reputation tab".

Comment: @David You need to use the Main Site user profile, not Meta: http://english.stackexchange.com/users/117675/david-pugh?tab=reputation

Comment: @Andrew: That is where I was, actually, foreseeing some such. But I must be really stupid tonight or all the time, 'cos I still don't get it. What I have is the geometrical thingy, which gives my rep but as a dead-end. To the right is my bio, to the right of that some stats, like how "old" I am on the site (12 days, so don't shoot me yet). Next line down, Communities, Top Tags, scores. Underneath that, Top Meta posts, Top Posts, links to All Questions Answers/Votes Newest. Bottom, Badges. I'm really sorry that you have to nursemaid me like this, I shall try to keep out of your hair from now.

Comment: @Andrew: Got it now. My mistake was to look on the Profile tab rather than Activity. I misinterpreted "look on your reputation tab in your profile".

Answer (score 0):

It is almost certainly the result of a question being removed, (either by the author or by the moderators), in which case all the reputation gained by others for answers or acceptances on that question is also removed. Try looking at your *Reputation* tab, ordered either by post or by date; you will probably see "-15 post removed" at some point. There is, by design, no way of telling who removed the post; and though it is occasionally possible for reputation to be conserved after such a removal, this is rare and depends on the historical significance of the post, not on your feelings about losing 15 points.

You might also try being more careful about your complaints. Levelling wild accusations of malice and incompetence simply because you haven't troubled to read the relevant sections of the Help is unlikely to predispose potential voters in your favour.

Comment: Yes, I found it. The Lord giveth, and the Lord taketh away? Sorry to be tetchy, I have had a run of troubles with the site, some of which were (perhaps) due to my African connection, some of which _may_ still be bugs. I don't understand, however, where "wild accusations of malice" reside in my question, please enlighten me. I named two possibilities, one of which was a FINE. It was at that stage possible in my mind that I had done something uncouth, without understanding what.

Comment: @DavidPugh I personally found nothing objectionable or antagonistic about your question, but I'll tell you I've leaned through hard experience that humor -- especially ironic humor -- presented in text rather than in person, falls flat (ie is misconstrued by the audience) often enough that it's not unfair to call its failure rate "catastrophic".  PS: the best advice I can give you at this point in your SE career is "ignore the reputation system", except to the extent you're gunning for specific privileges you intend to use (eg voting to close).

Comment: @Dan: No, I'm not so gunning. I don't have any specific ambitions other than to kill time in an educational (for me) and helpful (for others) manner. I shall resolve to not get too excited about stuff. But you know, this site is habit-forming, being appreciated is addictive. Is there a SE Anonymous?