# Update "What is Reputation?" page to include other rep-loss events

Tags: feature-request

Currently, under the ["what is reputation?"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) help page, we have a list of 7 ways you can gain reputation, and 5 ways you can lose it (receive downvote to question, receive downvote to answer, give downvote, place bounty, be flagged as a spammer/offender).

Unfortunately, those 5 ways are not actually the only ways for someone to lose rep, as evidenced by [several](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6787/why-reputation-is-lost-when-a-question-is-deleted) [recent](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6804/i-just-lost-15-in-one-go-a-fine) [questions](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6788/why-am-i-losing-two-reputation). Can we add a few more elements?  Specifically:

> - accepted answer is un-accepted: -15
> - upvoted answer is un-upvoted: -10
> - upvoted question is un-upvoted: -5
> - post *(question or answer)* is deleted: lose all rep points gained from that post

Suggestions for wording on that last item are welcome.  :-)  Also, are there any other ways that I've missed?

Comment: Vote reversal is already mentioned, but the others could be too. You should really ask this on [meta.se] though.

Comment: Yes, I agree with @curiousdannii, this should be asked on SE meta. You'll probably get faster answers too. As for the wording, as a newcomer I would not understand what the terms  "un-accepted" "un-upvoted" etc mean. Probably ‘reversed upvote’ or ‘backtracked upvote’ would be clearer, but I realise it's wordier.